# Application-layer overhearing in ad hoc networks, much like TCP

Tags: tcp, udp, wifi, adhoc, osi

I want to deploy an application on mobile devices participating in a WiFi ad hoc network that improves information robustness. The primary task is pretty simple: Send data (may be of bigger size) from a node S (source) to node D (destination). Here is my sample topology:

```
    --- N1 ---
   /    |     \
  /     |      \
S ----- N2 ----- N4 ----- D
  \     |      /
   \    |     /
    --- N3 ---
```

By simply using TCP, I can set up a reliable communication channel from S over N2 and N4 to D. That's ok.

My problem now is: I want that N1 and N3 can also get (overhear) the messages sent by S, N2 and N4, but they don't need to get it reliably. You can think of it as a flow of packets. For example, S wants to send a packet to D. But this packet may be useful for N[1-4], too - and should therefore be stored.

This is of course possible by using the promiscuous WiFi mode on all nodes, but that would be an overkill - because it would mean that every node would have to parse all packets to see if they can store them.

A simple solution would be to send UDP packets:

1. S sends UDP broadcast packet with a time-to-live of 1 to N2 with additional information.
2. N1, N2 and N3 can receive and store the packet, but only N2 resends the information to N4.
3. This behaviour repeats itself until D gets the package.

But then I have to somehow reimplement TCP in terms of packet ordering, congestion control and reliable communication - which is bad.

So my question is: Do you know about a protocol which supports this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what you are saying, and there are a couple of ways to do it. Using linux is the easiest, and the only platform where I have actually implemented this.

On linux there are two ways you can do this. 
1., use iptables and NQUEUE and pass received packets to an application process that do whatever you want with them. Use iptables rules to only pass up packets you are interested in, such as those with IP dst N2, N4 etc.
2. use libpcap, and link you program with this library and configure a capture filter to capture the packets you are interested in.

Comment: Ok, so basically you would recommend to do this on a lower OSI layer - but then also every packet has to be read (at least by iptables or libpcap). What I am looking for is a solution on OSI application level, meaning that I can keep the lower layers untouched. The final program should be able to run as a userspace program without having to be root...

Comment: What I am suggesting is a userspace app, but you would need to be root to run it, unless you sudo your application. You could however, split the app in two as one root and one nonroot. You want your application to be an application layer app, but do not want to use promiscuous mode. On the other hand you want specific nodes to receive only specific packets, which is a network layer operation. You are contradicting yourself, because what you are asking for will be always be a mechanism operating on several layers. You have the tools to do what you want to do, you need to decide how to proceed.

Comment: I am marking this answer as the correct answer because I think my approach is not as feasible as I thought initially, and Andy pointed out what it would take to overhear packages. I think it is feasible without touching the lower layers, but it would require that the application is running on every node.